# How to share single image post on facebook in basic HTML?

Tags: html, facebook, api, twitter, share

I have an Image Gallery with 16 images in basic HTML.
When a user clicks on an image, the image will pop up. Nothing else.
I added *Facebook*, *Twitter* and *Google+* icons on every image, but is it possible to share every single image on Facebook?
I am only able to share the website link, but I want to share those 16 images separately on Facebook.
So when a user clicks on an image to share to Facebook, then only this image will be shared, not the other 15 images.

Please give me some ideas.
I have been struggling with this the last few days.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Use the share button social plugin and make it specific to each image (see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/share-button/ ).  Be sure to read the section titled "Can I use the Share Dialog without using the Share Button?"